# The general and particular in the psychology of mathematics education

Tags: reference-request, student-motivation, teacher-preparation, teacher-training, teacher-motivation

Many students I have spoken with who are drawn to becoming mathematics teachers chose their mathematics major because they enjoyed doing routine exercises in high school. The comfort of a definite and systematic general procedure that eliminates uncertainty is somehow a major motivation for these students to pursue mathematics.

The above motivation stands in stark contrast to the attitudes of math olympiad enthusiasts and Eastern European colleagues raised on a diet of competition-type problems. It seems to me that the major motivation for these sorts of mathematics students is to collect an enormous store of problems that each stand out because of a distinguishing solution twist.

Being overly simple minded, let me assume that for the first group the comfort in mathematics comes from the general coherence of a system, and from the second it comes from the charm of particular phenomena. (Forgive the binary nature of this, but I would like to use it as a way to tease out what I want to isolate.)

Q: Are there papers in the literature that study the motivation of students for studying mathematics in terms of their placement on the "general-particular" spectrum suggested by the above extremes? If so, can someone please point me to some of these papers?

I ask this because I'm interested in "converting" some students from the first to second motivating viewpoint, and the first point of view seems rather persistent. (I am trying to do this not because I believe that the problem solving culture is necessarily "best", but that it seems a better alternative to the first point of view.)

---

Edit: On a somewhat related note that I will post here because it should not take up space elsewhere, at the root of this question is the more fundamental question of "sustainable mathematical motivation". Making the (certainly misguided) assumption that the "telos" of a mathematics student should be a productive research mathematician, the "general" or perhaps "scientific" viewpoint may be more sustainable (think about a Bourbaki approach) since one can follow naturality and pretty much continuously record observations about a mathematical question until something comes out of it…and this can probably be done steadily for an entire career, assuming one does not become disenchanted facing the tremendous stamina needed for such an approach. On the other hand, the ability to find delight in shorter bursts throughout the problemist literature can lead to the continual building of technical strength that can be brought to bear on many different problems, and such an approach is perhaps more sustainable due to the little bursts of drama found in each problem. In reality, mathematicians lie on a spectrum in their tastes and time-management inclinations…so the present question is slanted by the assumption that the latter sort of taste is the more human, and thus more sustainable. (A bad Erdos is better than a bad Grothendieck...)

Comment: I would suggest a third way:  collecting narratives.  I certainly do not care about memorizing systematic solutions to particular general sorts of problems.  I also do not care much for "tricky" solutions needed for particular problems.  I much prefer developing *stories*:  This kind of problem seems hard because of X, but when you think of it in context Y, we can now apply method Z, and so everything becomes clear.

Comment: @Steven Gubkin: Thanks for articulating this intuition! I also find the development of such stories a strong motivation for doing math...not to mention the relevant pictures to go with the stories!

Comment: It seems to me that the first point of view is more scientific (reducing seemingly disparate phenomena to orderly patterns), whereas the second point of view is more narrative (tell a familiar story with a twist).  I would argue that the first point of view is more powerful, as demonstrated by Kepler and Mendeleev.  In practice, where along this spectrum are people most likely to test hypotheses?

Comment: On the other hand, different students need different explanations before they can correctly understand and apply various concepts.  My mother was a foreign language teacher.  She taught me that I need to be able to explain things five different ways -- and come up with a sixth and a seventh when a student comes at things from yet another angle.  So the first viewpoint might result in simpler lesson plans that help most students who "get it" based on a standard approach, but the second viewpoint might result in teachers who are more effective at dealing with "But why?" and "Huh?" questions.

Comment: The two groups described in the problem don't sound like anyone I've ever met. This applies especially to the first group. Are there really people who enjoy solving routine exercises using predefined algorithms? That's what computers are for. If there are such people, I would imagine that they weren't very bright, or maybe that they were on the autism spectrum.

Comment: @Jasper: This very point has interested me in the past. One might argue that a systematic "Bourbaki" approach is closer to the scientific method than the approach of the typical contemporary mathematician.

Comment: @BenCrowell  I regularly meet people who say that they enjoy math for this reason.

Comment: Here, even is a fourth way: the pursuit of a conversation about mathematical topics. Somehow, "story" may even be isolated and one-sided. In its development mathematics may be more the development of a conversation…Lakatos anyone?

Comment: @BenCrowell "Are there really people who enjoy solving routine exercises using predefined algorithms?" Just going to pile on here: Oh god yes. I think it's an open theory that perhaps most people who want to be secondary-school math teachers may be in that category.

Comment: @DanielR.Collins - I fully agree regarding the existence question Ben Crowell expressed skepticism about. But as someone who began my career as a HS math teacher and still identifies that way, I feel (on behalf of all of us) a little slandered by the "open theory" comment. IMO, it is common for postsecondary mathematicians and math educators to see MS and HS teachers in a condescending way and fail to appreciate or really even see what we do. This comment (doubtless unintentionally) plays into that. I offer this in the hope of making the conversation more inclusive.

Comment: @benblumsmith: You are right that it is vitally important to keep the conversation here very inclusive, and I appreciate your comment. I feel the need to comment here because I think it would be a loss to remove the "open theory" comment, because certain prominent and active mathematics educators who are concerned primarily with the training of teachers at the MS and HS level have expressed this same theory, developed through long and intimate experience working with schools and future teachers.

Comment: (cont.) These persons have articulated that the system may be structured in such a way that it selects, e.g., future HS teachers who enjoy the aspect of mathematical practice closest to applying algorithms or algebraic technique over, say, numerical or geometric reasoning. I comment because I don't think the "open theory" comment is born of pure ignorance. (I'm sorry I don't have sources, these bits are from personal communications I've had with the mathematics educators in question.)

Comment: I am reminded of your older question: [Teaching and "The Two Cultures"](http://matheducators.stackexchange.com/questions/2213/teaching-and-the-two-cultures).

Comment: @J W: Indeed, I find myself cycling around this theme. Perhaps I'm just a helpless dualist... LOL!

Comment: 1.  I would be cautious with this simplistic view of drill is bad/mindless and research is uh-mazing.  It's typical emotive ed-speak labeling with loaded terms. For one thing, it's very hard to do good math research without rock solid skills.

Comment: 2.  I would caution you against pushing too hard to get teachers to abandon drill.  Do you like getting kids who can't handle fractions?  who make "dumb mistakes" on signs or combining terms of algebra that inhibits them following a derivation or executing a multi step problem?  For that matter how many typical students do you knw that do too much homework after already internalizing a skill (and comitting it to long term memory and the ability to retrieve, including after gaps in use)?

Comment: 3.  I would also caution you to realize the differences of Ph.D. pure math types like yourself versus students (and the teachers of them) who need the service training in algebra and calculus to support doing homeworks in fluid flow, thermodynamics, and AC transmission.  And do not have unlimited time to go down the math rat hole.  They need to learn what a wye-delta transformer is also.  Etc.

Answer (score 2):

To the question about whether or not there is existant literature around some of these ideas, I believe there is a great deal.  It seems you are getting at conversations around proof and how this plays out in teachers beliefs about mathematics. Several researchers have engaged in such pursuits.  Immediately two things come to mind.

- The ICMI study on proof in mathematics education: https://books.google.com.sa/books?id=qA_lLat89BMC&printsec=frontcover&hl=ar&source=gbs_ge_summary_r&cad=0#v=onepage&q&f=false
- Patricio Herbst and Daniel Chazan have both done research in these areas, you'll find a good deal of references in their work as well.

Comment: Could you perhaps [edit](http://matheducators.stackexchange.com/posts/11301/edit) your answer to provide more detail, such as a brief summary of the research, along with a clearer explanation of how this fits in with the "general-particular" spectrum mentioned by the OP?